# webpack angular starter - $ definition

Tags: angular, webpack

I've build starter app using [Angular 2 Starter by AngularClass](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). In console (both Chrome and firebug) I can type:

```
a = $('body')
```

And `a` is of type object and it looks like it is DOM element. I can't run

```
a.find('h1')
```

Where does this `$` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is selector function on browser api. you can console the same in chrome:

```
$ //type $ in console log
function$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] } //returns function
```

checking if it exists on window :

```
window.$
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

It simply returns the macthed element from DOM. The reason why `a.find('h1')` is not working because the `find` is not function on the `$` selector function. It has nothing to do with webpack or angular2.